# SQL alchemy basequery object contains multiple classes - how do I paginate the results/convert to one single table?

Tags: python, sql, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

In an app for learning words, I have 2 classes, `User` and `Word` and a third class `UserWordList`, which represents the relationship between the two classes.

```
class UserWordList(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
   word_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('word.id'))
```

I have included an attribute in the `User` class to display the list of words currently being studied as:

```
words_learned_list = (db.session.query(Word,UserWordList)
    .filter(Word.id == UserWordList.word_id)
    .filter(UserWordList.user_id == id))
```

This all works fine, however I would like to print a list of the words for the user using paginate and the `words_learned_list` is formed of tuples of class instances, which are not printable. Is there a way to convert this list into one single table?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not Create a view inside the database, and then a single class for the two in python

Comment: The reason that I've done it this way is that the UserWordList will contain extra methods that I haven't included here.